# ReactJS - can't seem to run commands in desired order

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a find nearby restaurant app with ReactJS. I am working with Google Places Autocomplete with my Search Input. I am trying to get a geolocation, which seems to run smoothly.

What goes wrong is that whenever I select a place in the autocomplete dropdown, I run a function that passes a query string to translate to geolocation, my search result always renders items from the previous state of the latitude and longitude, and not the one that was fetched within the last run of the function.

I can't seem to get it right with the order these commands are executed in.

The function I am talking about looks like this:

```js
  handlePlaceSelect = () => {
    // Extract City From Address Object
    const addressObject = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
    const address = addressObject.address_components;
    const URL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${
      this.state.lat
    },${this.state.lng}&type=restaurant&radius=${5 *
      1000}&key=MYAPIKEY`;

    Geocode.setApiKey('MYAPIKEY');

    // Check if address is valid
    if (address) {
      // Set State
      this.setState({
        city: address[0].long_name,
        query: addressObject.formatted_address
      });
    }

    Geocode.fromAddress(this.state.query)
      .then(
        response => {
          const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
          this.setState({
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng
          });
        },
        error => {
          console.error(error);
        }
      )
      .then(
        axios
          .get(URL)
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            this.setState({ places: response.data.results });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.message);
          })
      );
  };
```

Also here is the rest of the code for this component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// Imports
import axios from 'axios';
import Script from 'react-load-script';
import { Button, SearchInput } from 'evergreen-ui';
import ResultsItem from '../../components/ResultsItem/ResultsItem.jsx';

import Geocode from 'react-geocode';

// Styles
import './Search.scss';

class Autocomplete extends Component {
  // Define Constructor
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Declare State
    this.state = {
      type: 'restaurant',
      radius: 10,
      lat: '59.0738',
      lng: '41.3226',
      city: '',
      query: '',
      open: false,
      places: []
    };

    this.currentLocationOnClick = this.currentLocationOnClick.bind(this);
    this.handlePlaceSelect = this.handlePlaceSelect.bind(this);
  }

  currentLocationOnClick() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        this.setState({ lat: position.coords.latitude });
        this.setState({ lng: position.coords.longitude });
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error getting location');
      }
    );
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=
    ${this.state.lat},${this.state.lng}type=restaurant&radius=${2 *
      1000}&key=MYAPIKEY`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ places: data.results });
    console.log(data.results);
  }

  handleScriptLoad = () => {
    // Declare Options For Autocomplete
    const options = {
      types: ['address']
    }; // To disable any eslint 'google not defined' errors

    // Initialize Google Autocomplete
    /*global google*/ this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById('autocomplete'),
      options
    );

    // Avoid paying for data that you don't need by restricting the set of
    // place fields that are returned to just the address components and formatted
    // address.
    this.autocomplete.setFields(['address_components', 'formatted_address']);

    // Fire Event when a suggested name is selected
    this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', this.handlePlaceSelect);
  };

  handlePlaceSelect = () => {
    // Extract City From Address Object
    const addressObject = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
    const address = addressObject.address_components;
    const URL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${
      this.state.lat
    },${this.state.lng}&type=restaurant&radius=${5 *
      1000}&key=MYAPIKEY`;

    Geocode.setApiKey('MAAPIKEY');

    // Check if address is valid
    if (address) {
      // Set State
      this.setState({
        city: address[0].long_name,
        query: addressObject.formatted_address
      });
    }

    Geocode.fromAddress(this.state.query)
      .then(
        response => {
          const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
          this.setState({
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng
          });
        },
        error => {
          console.error(error);
        }
      )
      .then(
        axios
          .get(URL)
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            this.setState({ places: response.data.results });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.message);
          })
      );
  };

  render() {
    const findPlacesOnClick = () => {
      const URL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${
        this.state.lat
      },${this.state.lng}&type=restaurant&radius=${5 *
        1000}&key=MYAPIKEY`;
      axios
        .get(URL)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.setState({ places: response.data.results });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error.message);
        });
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="search">
          <SearchInput
            id="autocomplete"
            placeholder="Search by address"
            width="100%"
            height={56}
          />
          <Button onClick={this.currentLocationOnClick}>
            {this.state.lat} & {this.state.lng}
          </Button>

          <Button appearance="primary" onClick={findPlacesOnClick}>
            Fetch
          </Button>

          <Script
            url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&libraries=places,geometry&callback=initAutocomplete"
            onLoad={this.handleScriptLoad}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="results">
          {this.state.places.map(places => (
            <div className="results-item" onClick={this.props.sideBarOpen}>
              <ResultsItem name={places.name} />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Autocomplete;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setState` function can be *asynchronous*. The `this.state` object is most likely not going to be updated with what you passed into `this.setState` until the next render.

The workaround for that is to put the stuff you want to happen *after* the state change in a callback:

```
this.setState({
  city: address[0].long_name,
  query: addressObject.formatted_address
}, state => {
  // the rest of the code
});
```

...or to stick with atomic state changes only. This is preferred if you don't need a re-render between the two `setState` calls:

```
handlePlaceSelect = async () => {
  let { query } = this.state;

  // Extract City From Address Object
  const addressObject = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
  const address = addressObject.address_components;
  Geocode.setApiKey('MYAPIKEY');

  // Check if address is valid
  let city;
  if (address) {
    city = address[0].long_name;
    query = addressObject.formatted_address
  }

  let lat, lng;
  try {
    const response = await Geocode.fromAddress(query);
    ({ lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }

  let places;
  try {
    const URL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${lat},${lng}&type=restaurant&radius=${5 * 1000}&key=MYAPIKEY`;
    const response = await axios.get(URL)
    console.log(response.data);
    places = response.data.results;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }

  this.setState({ query, places, city, lat, lng });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt answer — I am getting this error now —
Unhandled Rejection (ReferenceError): Cannot access 'lat' before initialization

Comment: Fixed it, @AdamSchwarcz

Comment: Okay, I am not getting an error now. It didn't seem to get my problem right though. My problem is that whenever I try to fetch restaurants what renders on the interface are restaurant from the previous state. What happens is after I select a street in autocomplete dropdown:

1. I select first street — nothing renders
2. I select second street — render restaurants near first street

Comment: I think what needs to happen is that setState (mainly for lng & lat) has to run before the axios makes the API call @Jacob

Comment: Yes, you're right; it looks like you should build the URL just before you call Axios so it's using the latest data (updated to do that).

Comment: And maybe you could help me further — can I do the same this with this part of the code? It's another button that gets your current location

`currentLocationOnClick() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        this.setState({ lat: position.coords.latitude });
        this.setState({ lng: position.coords.longitude });
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error getting location');
      }
    );
  }`

Comment: That should be ok since you're not referring to `this.state` right after calling `this.setState`, but IMO it's cleaner to set both state properties at the same time so React doesn't queue two different updates.

Comment: What I need to do is that once I get the current location successfully I want to make an API call and update the state of place so my interface renders a refreshed link.. Now I remade to look like this (look in the updated thrad above... this comment has character limits). I also get the same problem here.. I run the code first time and nothing renders, only after the second run